# Listing out system calls that return a file descriptor

Tags: linux, system-calls

Is there any documentation on what values are returned by a system call on linux? I'm specifically looking for system calls that return file descriptors. Is manually going through each system calls description the only way?

EDIT: The [documentation here seems helpful](http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#exit).

Comment: I did not mean the libc `system` call. I meant `system calls`.

Comment: Oh..i see my mistake.. may be this one help you http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_File-IO_Through_System_Calls